# Trying to add two numbers, but it doesn't work

Tags: c#

```
Console.WriteLine("What is the first number?");
var svar_regneart01 = Console.ReadLine(); 
Console.WriteLine("What would you like to add to {0}?", svar_regneart01);
var svar_regneart02 = Console.ReadLine(); 
Console.WriteLine("The answer is " + (svar_regneart01 + svar_regneart02));
```

I'm trying to add the two variables together but they just print out next to each other. The reason I use the `var` keyword is because I want the person who is playing to be able to use either integers or floats.

Comment: Sounds like you have strings.

Comment: Use `double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: Do not use `double.Parse` unless you *know* that the string contains a double.  Use `TryParse` if the string might not contain a double.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding strings concatenates the strings.

Use `TryParse` to parse the strings into integers or doubles. Remember to check the return value! You *must* handle the case where the user fails to type in a valid number.

> The reason I use the `var` keyword is because I want the person who is playing be able to choose both integers and floats.

You don't understand what `var` means.  `var` means "replace `var` with the type of the thing on the right", and the thing on the right is of type `string`.  It does not mean "allow any value in this variable".

Comment: @KasparTvedtMoberg, a little googling would probably have gotten you to [Microsoft's documentation for `Double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx).  That documentation will tell you the method signature (`public static bool TryParse(string s, out double result)`).  So we know it takes a `string` and returns a `bool`, also setting the `result` parameter.  This should give you a clue where to put it in your code, but if you're still stumped, you can find example usage farther down on the page.  With these skills you'll be able to find answers on your own.